# Is a kernel patch available for 32-bit instances of RHEL 5?

Tags: rhel, kernel, vulnerability

I know RHEL 5 is old, but could someone confirm if there's an Extended Support Meltdown patch available for RHEL *32-bit*? I've heard that Red Hat only has a 64-bit kernel fix out now but when I reviewed the [errata page](https://access.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2018:0292) it looked to be like 32-bit kernel packages were available. Could I get a second (or third) pair of eyes here before I contact Red Hat?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a 32-bit Meltdown/Spectre patch in the extended support kernel for RHEL 5. AFAIK it relies on hardware support for certain features, so depending on the age of your 32-bit system it might not be effective, but it is present. It also appears to only address the Spectre vulnerabilities; the Meltdown fixes for 32-bit x86 [are still being worked on](https://lwn.net/Articles/752551/).

If your RHEL 5 system is registered with the subscription manager, the update should be available — see [this support article](https://access.redhat.com/articles/11258) for details.